# Changing pixel glitter to a fill of vector art in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, texture, fill, graphic-styles, object-styles

Imagine this situation: You have received a screenshot of an animated glitter text as a raster image, and been asked to change the text, enlarge the image to prepare for print and apply the same fill effect (let me refer to it as pixel glitter).

You have converted it to vector to create the new, bigger text and you are ready to get the fill. But then you notice that your glitter has turned into thousands of paths with 3k colours (each one for each pixel)! Is there a way to grab this effect from the original raster image, and apply it as a fill to the vector objects in the bigger one?

Any tips, links, tutorials and ideas are welcome! Please share your suggestions, especially if this question looks really super simple to you (I'm a self-taught graphic designer and new here, so I ask you for your understanding). Thank you!

EDIT: Here are the parts of the files, with description of what I mean (thank you Rafael for your suggestion!)

[image: Here are the parts of the files]

Comment: We can Imagine, but an image would be helpful. But at the end I hope you charge the client to make a new image based on the screenshot.

Comment: Good point, @Rafael thanks for the idea! I have now attached the image of what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first idea would be

**1)** Reducing the palete of a copy of the original bitmap, to reduce the glitter totally. Another color selection with an extended range will do.

**2)** Making a texture to put inside the new vectorized shapes Using clipping tool. Probably a noise texture will be enough. You should play with the scale of this texture.

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing something in large format. Most large format printers would rather print a JPG then a PDf. I would get the text you vectored and enlarged, place it in photoshop finish the project there.

In photoshop select the inside of the text (where you want to fill the effect) 
Fill in the red, don't deselect.
Fliter>Noise>Add Noise> 
Make sure you play with the settings. I recommend monochrome selected.

Then don't deselect yet. If it doesn't complete the effect how you imagined it 
1) play with some adjustments (levels, hue and sat) 
2) Try a different noise filter.

Hope this helps